# How to generate all possible tree with the total node of node N

Tags: c, data-structures, tree

I try to figure out how to generate all possible tree from a set of unidentical node (Each node is labeled as A,B,C,D,... ) with the size of N. Anyhelp with this problem?

Comment: Can you give an example? I don't understand your question fully. Also, provide us with some more details of the "grander" problem you are trying to solve, perhaps there is a better way.

Comment: 1) Are the trees rooted? 2)How large can the N be? - the number of trees grows exponentially with N

Comment: The trees are not rooted and the size of N is arbitrary (may be maximum 15). I think the problem should be "how to generate all possible spanning tree from a set of unidentical node". Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Eric Lippert [explains how to do this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/04/22/every-tree-there-is.aspx).

Read the entire series; it's too long to copy here.

Comment: The discussion on the link is for unlabeled vertices (looking only at the tree structure instead)

Comment: missingno is correct -- my articles only give instructions on how to generate all the *shapes*, but in this case, a tree of the form (A (B C)) is different than (B (A C)) and so on. It is pretty easy to adapt the solution though;  basically you need a combination of all the *permutations* of the label set and all the possible tree shapes.

Comment: Since my tree is not rooted, all possible permutation for the same shape will create many redundant trees. For example, (A (B (C))) will be the same as (C (B (A))).